# Why am I immediately getting a "Couldn't Connect" Toast when calling device.createBond()?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I am writing a Wear OS android app that is trying to connect to the Nonin 3150 BLE Pulse Oximeter. In its integration guide, it says you must connect to it then pair then bond then encrypt the connection, which already seems like more steps than the Android bluetooth setup guide.

Whatever method I try, the device connects or says it's connecting successfully then immediately disconnects without providing any error that I'm aware of.

I am trying this on a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 targeting SDK 32 (min 30).

If I do `bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)` then immediately call `device.connectGatt()`, I receive two back-to-back `onConnectionStateChange` calls. The first says `CONNECTED` with `GATT_SUCCESS` and the second says `DISCONNECTED` with `GATT_SUCCESS`. Calling `gatt.discoverServices()` when the `CONNECTED` state occurs does nothing.

If I try to call `device.createBond()` first then plan to call `device.connectGatt()` in the `BroadcastReceiver` callback, I don't even get that far. I press the button on screen that initiates the bond and immediately receive a Toast on screen saying "Couldn't Connect". I receive a callback for `BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING`, but nothing happens after that.

For more context, I am writing this as a Jetpack Compose app. I am new to the architecture, so I'm not sure if it matters, but I wrote a `Service` to represent the service and bound it to a ViewModel. All of this bluetooth code is being run in the service. The guide says the device uses the Just Works method of pairing. As an extra step, I tried calling `device.setPin("0000".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did u get any solution for this? i am facing the same problem?